# Is there a shortcut like <C-W>o that ignores the E445

Tags: key-bindings

In many cases I have one spare window which contains garbage and when I am in my main window, I'd like to close all other (with `<C-W>o`), but I am getting E445 for those that are not saved. 
Is there a relatively sort key combination that can close all other saved and not saved windows?

Comment: Try `:set hidden`

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for key combination that I will use only in some cases, not always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to dispose of the unpersisted buffers right away, you'd need to write a custom function that iterates over all visible buffers and `:bdelete!`s them.

However, I think it's better to postpone the problem until Vim is eventually closed. This behavior is built-in via the [`:help 'hidden'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27hidden%27) option.

If you don't want to set this permanently, you could just temporarily set it (I'm using the upper-case `O` key to avoid overriding the original mapping; you could also use the alternative `<C-o>`):

```
:nnoremap <C-w>O :set hidden<CR><C-w>o:set nohidden<CR>
```

That's ugly, we can use `:wincmd` to make a single, concatenated command-line:

```
:nnoremap <C-w>O :set hidden<Bar>wincmd o<Bar>set nohidden<CR>
```

But wait, there's a special [`:only`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Aonly) command that does the same:

```
:nnoremap <C-w>O :set hidden<Bar>only<Bar>set nohidden<CR>
```

And reading the documentation, this takes an optional `!` to force hiding *without having to set the option*. I think that's a winner:

```
:nnoremap <C-w>O :only!<CR>
```